# tinymce wiris plugin not showing formulas on form edit mode

Tags: tinymce

When I add formulas from tinymce wiris plugin, it's successfully added.
but when I see these in form edit mode it is not showing why ?

This is my code on edit content form :

```
tinymce.init({

    selector: '.text_editors', theme: "modern", height: 100,
    plugins: [
        "placeholder advlist autolink link image lists charmap hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code tiny_mce_wiris"
    ],
    toolbar1: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor code tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry tiny_mce_wiris_CAS",
    // toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
    image_advtab: true,
    external_filemanager_path: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/",
    filemanager_title: "Nactus Filemanager",
    external_plugins: {
        "filemanager": "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/plugin.min.js",
        // "tiny_mce_wiris": "<?php //echo $this->webroot;      ?>js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/plugin.js",
    }
});
```